# InstallUtil throwing exception when trying to install windows service on Windows 2012 server

Tags: installutil

I developed a windows service using VS 2010 (32 bit), but compiled it for 'Any CPU'.

I have transferred the required exe and other files onto a Windows 2012 Server (Standard edition - 64 bit), and am now trying to install it using InstallUtil

I have changed the path on my command prompt to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319", and run the command

InstallUtil "D:\MyPath\MyService.exe"

But the install fails with the error

```
    An exception occurred during the Install phase.
    System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, 
but some or all event logs could not be searched.  
Inaccessible logs: Security.
```

I have tried running `InstallUtil` as an administrator. The server doesn't have the Visual Studio command prompt.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be with the extension (.exe) and without the quotes. It is:

```
InstallUtil.exe D:\MyPath\MyService.exe
```

And if you are in "Windows PowerShell" you should add "/.". It is:

```
./InstallUtil.exe C:\ServicesExample\Services.MyService.exe
```

Always once you are on: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and running as Admin.